# asp.net CompositeDataBoundControl for a single object

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created a CompositeDataBoundControl that i can databind perfectly well.
Now i want to do the same thing, but not for a list of objects, but for a single object. 
Reasons is that i want my colleagues to have the ability to simply use the <%# Eval("X") %> in their front end code.

The problem is that the CompositeDataBoundControl has a method that i have to override, which only accepts a collection as a datasource

```
CreateChildControls(System.Collections.IEnumerable dataSource, bool dataBinding)
```

Is there a way to do the same thing for a single object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to override the **DataSource** property

```
public class SingleObjectView : CompositeDataBoundControl
    {
        private object dataSource;
        public override object DataSource
        {
            get { return new List<object> { dataSource }; }
            set { dataSource = value; }
        }


        protected override int CreateChildControls(System.Collections.IEnumerable dataSource, bool dataBinding)
        {
            SingleItem singleItem = null;
            if (dataBinding)
            {
                var it = dataSource.GetEnumerator();
                it.MoveNext();

                singleItem = new SingleItem(it.Current);
            }
            else
            {
                singleItem = new SingleItem(null);
            }

            ItemTemplate.InstantiateIn(singleItem);
            Controls.Add(singleItem);
            if (dataBinding)
                singleItem.DataBind();
            return 1;
        }


        [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty), TemplateContainer(typeof(SingleItem))]
        public ITemplate ItemTemplate { get; set; }
    }

    public class SingleItem : Control, IDataItemContainer
    {
        public SingleItem(object dataItem)
        {
            DataItem = dataItem;
        }
        public object DataItem { get; set; }

        public int DataItemIndex
        {
            get { return 0; }
        }

        public int DisplayIndex
        {
            get { return 0; }
        }
    }
```

**edit to show the usage**

```
<ctrl:SingleObjectView ID="productView" runat="server">
   <ItemTemplate>
        <%# Eval("ProductName") %>
        <br />
        <%# Eval("Price","{0:c}") %>
   </ItemTemplate>
</ctrl:SingleObjectView>

 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
      {
        productView.DataSource = new { ProductName="My Product", Price="10"};
        productView.DataBind();
      }
 }
```

So the DataSource receives an object which doesn't implement `IEnumerable`, but overriding the DataSource property of the `SingleObjectView` control, ensures that `CreateChildControls` is called.

Comment: This is exactly what TysHHTP is trying to do.

Comment: @AngeloBad, this control I wrote is used like this: ctrlSingleObjectView.DataSource = singleObject; ctrlSingleObjectView.DataBind(); I believe it's exactly what OP needs.

Comment: Today i had time to test and implement this solution and i must say, it works exactly as i wanted. Thanks! To bad that i wasn't anywhere near a computer when the bounty for this problem had to be awarded. It definitely belongs to this answer.

Comment: @TysHTTP, glad if it helped you. If you encounter any problem with this control, don't hesitate to leave a comment here.

Answer (score 2):

What about create a list of control, add one single object and then call the method?

Comment: We figured that out as well, but it feels more as a workaround/hack than as a decent solution.

Comment: If a method accept an IEnumerable as parameter, passing an IEnumerable composed by only 1 element is not an hack. Do you know what I mean?

Answer (score 0):

I use [FormView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.formview.aspx) to allow an instance of a single object to be templated:

```
  protected void fvProduct_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      // Load product template
      fvProduct.ItemTemplate = LoadTemplate("Templates/ProductTemplate.ascx");

      // Bind product to data source
      fvProduct.DataSource = new[] { Product };
      fvProduct.DataBind();
  }
```

Then in `ProductTemplate.ascx` you can do stuff like this:

```
<h1><%# Eval("ProductName") %></h1>
<p><%# Eval("Description") %></p>
<h4><%# Eval("Price", "{0:C}")%></h4>
```

In your scenario you mentioned you were using a custom control but the idea is basically the same as the answers above. You just create an enumerable with one item and bind it. The reason for using a `FormView` is because it is designed to only display exactly one item at a time.